Intl.NumberFormat Decimal Style Cannot Handle Number More Than 17 Character
I tried to create a formatter for amount in Rupiah with Intl.NumberFormat with decimal format. But when the input number exceeds 17 digits, the number displayed becomes messy and does not match the input.
Here's My formatter Code :

export const convertWithDelimiter = (value: string): string => {
  const amountValue = parseFloat(value)
  const formatter = Intl.NumberFormat('id-ID', {
    style: 'decimal',
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
  });

  return value ? formatter.format(amountValue) : '';
};

Is there any way that Intl.NumberFormat with decimal format can handle numbers longer than 17 characters?


You've reached the limit of JavaScript's number precision.

It has nothing to do with NumberFormat. If you have a number that large, it can't be printed accurately in any way.

const amountValue = BigInt(value)


Is there any way that Intl.NumberFormat with decimal format can handle
numbers longer than 17 characters?

According to Mozilla...
MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
+/- 9,007,199,254,740,991  

Which is just over 9 Quadrillion!
So even for the Indian rupee... isn't nine quadrillion rupees enough for you?
Come on man, you're exaggerating! :)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
Anyway, the next level up is BigInt... but don't get too excited because they've got lots of limitations you can read about here...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt
